# Want to be able to change password using variable

Tags: c#

I am a beginner at C# and I am learning. I am using a password to enter into a main screen I created. At the moment I have the password just set to PASSWORD. Once I enter PASSWORD and click a login button, certain buttons are enabled. They were previously disabled. I would like to be able to enter the password as a variable and then have the option to change the password. I am having difficulty setting up the password as a variable. Here is the code I am using for the password.

```
private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "PASSWORD")              
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = false;
            button3.Enabled = true;
            button4.Enabled = true;
            button5.Enabled = true;
            button6.Enabled = true;
            button7.Enabled = true;
            button8.Enabled = true;
            button9.Enabled = true;
            button10.Enabled = true;
            button11.Enabled = true;
            button12.Enabled = false;
            button16.Enabled = true;
            button16.Visible = true;
            button20.Enabled = true;
            numericUpDown1.Enabled = true;
            numericUpDown2.Enabled = true;

            button14.Click += ResetTimer;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Password is Incorrect");
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

I have tried

```
String PassWord; 
PassWord = "Password";
```

but don't know where to go next.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you,

Comment: As example you need a textfile where the password is saved. Then you save the password of the textfile in a variable and check it against the user input.

Comment: The question is rather general - better ask for specific details. Where are your problems? However, in general you will need to: load old password and compare with input, have password change dialog (usually asks for old password, new password and repeat), save new password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to have a default password as "PASSWORD" i.e for the first time, after logging once you want to change the password to desired one.
For that:

```
String PassWord;
PassWord = "PASSWORD";
if (textBox1.Text == PassWord)
```

now you can add controls to change this password string. I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: if (textBox1.Text == PassWord) make this correction. and now add textbox control to have new password, and store it in PassWord string.

Comment: I think there's a typo in your comment. Password. Not "assword"

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer (and upvote) if it resolved your problem.

Comment: @ritzz.soni thank you. Ihave created new text boxes for the enter old password, new password and confirm password. Would this be correct? if (textBox2.Text == PassWord)
            {               
                MessageBox.Show("Password is Correct");                                }

Comment: and if (textBox3.Text == textBox4.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Password Changed");   }

Comment: for checking the password : if (textBox2.Text == PassWord) this check works fine.  now to change password if ((textBox3.Text == textBox4.Text) && (textBox3.Text != " ")){ PassWord = textBox3.Text; MessageBox.Show("Password Changed");} will work.

Comment: @ritzz.soni thanks again. What do I put above if (textBox2.Text == PassWord) ? Is it String PassWord; PassWord = "PASSWORD"

Comment: yeah put that...and Don't forget to accept this answer (and upvote) if it resolved your problem

Comment: @ritz.soni the password isn't changing when I try this.For enter password this is the code im using: String PassWord; PassWord = "PASSWORD"; if(textBox1.Text ==PassWord) { }                                                                                                           For the change password im using this:String PassWord;PassWord = "PASSWORD";if (textBox2.Text == PassWord) { }
and  String PassWord; if((textBox3.Text == textBox4.Text) && (textBox3.Text != " ")) {PassWord = textBox3.Text; MessageBox.Show("Password Changed");  Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: can you tell me how exactly your application work. what comes on the screen at first?

Comment: First I enter PASSWORD into textbox1 and click login and it enables buttons I use. Then I have 3 more textboxes 2, 3 and 4. Textbox 2 is where I enter the old password. Textbox 3 is where I enter new password and textbox 4 is where I enter new password again. So I want the new password to be used next time to log into textbox1.

Comment: see for that you need to use database. create a database with default password as PASSWORD.
and then use the code mentioned above, but instead using password = "PASSWORD" fetch password from database, and do 
if((textBox3.Text == textBox4.Text) && (textBox3.Text != " "))
 {PassWord = textBox3.Text;
 MessageBox.Show("Password Changed");}
then store this password in database. so next time you will fetch this password will be there.

Comment: I think that will solve your query and Don't forget to accept this answer (and upvote) if it resolved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Put your password value in the database and retrieve it from there.
Then compare it to the value entered from the textbox.